# How to refer to chart title in Shapes()?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to format a chart in a new tab based on some existing data from a worksheet. I can record the pattern using "Save As Template", but I want to create a macro that creates the same format every time. However, I have some problem with referring to the chart. Here's my code.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim GraphTab As Object
    Set GraphTab = ActiveSheet

   'Change everything to Times New Roman
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(GraphTab).TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .NameComplexScript = "Times New Roman"
        .NameFarEast = "Times New Roman"
        .Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Size = 10
    End With
End Sub
```

I receive an error message starting from this line `With ActiveSheet.Shapes(GraphTab).TextFrame2.TextRange.Font`.

Ideally, I also want the `GraphTab` to be updated every time I manually change the tab name. Is that possible?

Comment: The `.Shapes()` argument is expecting a `String` with the shape name in it. The way the code is written it tries to pass an `Object` into that argument that happens to be a worksheet object as set by `GraphTab = ActiveSheet`. Does the chart name you want share the same name as the worksheet?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes, I want my chart name the same name as the worksheet. How should I do that?

Comment: First, are you trying to make a new chart? Move an existing chart to a new worksheet? Or just rename a chart on the current sheet? And how many charts on the sheet?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman For this exercise, let's assume the chart is already in new worksheet, and the new worksheet has only the chart object.

Comment: Shawn. See my answer below. I will elaborate on how it will automatically change the title of the chart if the sheet name is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment, this code has been tested to produce the desired results.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("NewChartSheet") ' change name as needed

    ws.Range("A1").Formula = "=RIGHT(CELL(""filename"",A1),LEN(CELL(""filename"",A1))-FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",A1)))        

    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Set cht = ws.ChartObjects(1) 'since just one chart on page, it's the first one in the collection

    With cht.Chart.ChartTitle
        With .Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
            .NameComplexScript = "Times New Roman"
            .NameFarEast = "Times New Roman"
            .Name = "Times New Roman"
            .Size = 10
        End With
        .Caption = "=NewChartSheet!R1C1"
    End With

End Sub
```

To understand how the chart title is set up to automatically change if the sheet name is changed see below:

1. The `.Caption = "=NewChartSheet!R1C1"` sets the chart title to equal the value in cell A1
2. The `ws.Range("A1").Formula` sets the formula to show the sheet name.
3. The formula in `A1` uses the `filename` argument of the [CELL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CELL-function-51BD39A5-F338-4DBE-A33F-955D67C2B2CF) function, which returns the full file path, file name and sheet name, of the referenced cell.
4. The formula manipulates the format of the filename further to return just the sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the solution you've been looking for:

```
With Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.ChartTitle
    .Text = "test"
    .Font.FontStyle = "Times New Roman"
    .Font.Size = 10
End With
```

If you are using the sheet's code name instead of the sheet name then the code will still work when you are changing the name of the graph sheet. If you meant to change the chart name then I would integrate a loop like so

```
For Each cht In Sheet1.ChartObjects
    With cht.Chart.ChartTitle
        .Text = "test"
        .Font.FontStyle = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Size = 10
    End With
Next cht
```